# how to view other user google calendar events for same domain (c# will be preferrable)

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api

how to search events present in other users google calendar by Rest API in c#. I tried using sdk and it ask for credentials(logged in user). If we provide primary as key word in clientid it will show only the one logged in. i want for others. Just like in calendar add event. In that find a time which i want to implement through api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A users google calendar data is private.  You can not access a users data without their permission.  When you login to google calendar using Oauth2 you request access of a user.  Once that users grants you access to **their** data you may access that data.  you may not access data owned by another user at that time.

If you want to search in the other users data you need to be authenticated as them.  If you want to search in several users data you will need to be authenticated as each of them as you are searching.